# Raise ValueError if file not found

Tags: python, error-handling

I would like to raise a ValueError if a file is not found. Currently I have the following:

```
def read_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f: 
        #do something
    except ValueError:
        print("File not found")
```

However, this just returns a FileNotFoundError: if the file isn't found

Comment: All builtin exception have a special meaning. A ValueError is less of a match if a file can't be opened than the original exceptions (can be many different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch `IOError` instead, and inside the except block, raise a `ValueError`.

```
try:
    with open(filename, "r") as f: 
    #do something
except IOError:
    raise ValueError("File not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be a little more explicit and raise `ValueError` as Python provides the ability to not only catch built-in exceptions but raise them too.

```py
def read_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            pass # do something
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise ValueError("File not found")
```

Comment: A missing file triggers an `IOError`, not a `ValueError`, so this except will never be caught.

Comment: Sure, makes sense.

Comment: @JohnGordon I was just playing around, it seems a better exception to catch would be `FileNotFoundError` rather than IOError. Please check the updated answer.